# jQuery get data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am fetching the data from mysql table in an array which is in multi dimensional array. So the data is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [client_id] => 2
            [first_name] => test1
            [last_name] => test2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [client_id] => 2
            [first_name] => test3
            [last_name] => test4
        )

)
```

As I need the data in json format So I made like this
json_encode( $users );

It gave me result like this

```
[{"id":"2","client_id":"2","first_name":"test1","last_name":"test2"},
{"id":"3","client_id":"2","first_name":"test3","last_name":"test4"}]
```

As I wanted to get the data in object I did like this

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

which gave me data in two objects. Now I want to get data for first_name . So can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: .each(() function from jquery??

Comment: yes..but how to do for a multidimensional array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery `each` function. for example, the following code might help you :

```
var obj = 
        [{"id":"2","client_id":"2","first_name":"test1","last_name":"test2"},
        {"id":"3","client_id":"2","first_name":"test3","last_name":"test4"}];

        $.each(obj,function(i,o){
            alert(o.id);
        });
```

Let me know if you seeking something else :)

Answer (score 0):

`data[i]['first_name']` will give you first name. use loops for iterations on i

Answer (score 0):

After successful add data in `JS` variable then you can get `first_name` by the for look, see below

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  console.log(data[i].first_name)
}
```